# Magento2 Event 'customer_register_success' or 'customer_login' for adding product to Wishlist

Tags: magento2

I've created Guest Wishlist and now I am trying to add products from cookie to a Customer Wishlist.

Problem is that if I observe 'customer_register_success' wishlist is not created until new customer is fully logged in.

If I observe 'customer_login' then problem is that I want to add products from cookie to a Wishlist ONLY if it is a new registered customer.

Not sure how to get newly registered customer wishlist?

Here is my observer ($list is array of product Ids, from a cookie named 'guestwishlist':

```
namespace Vendor\GuestWishlist\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;

class CreateAccount implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /** @var WishlistFactory */
    protected $wishlistFactory;

    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
        \Vendor\GuestWishlist\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');
        $customerId = $customer->getId();

        $list = $this->_helper->getGuestWishlist();

        if(isset($list)){

            foreach ($list as $productId){

                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

                $wishlist = $this->wishlistFactory->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
                $wishlist->addNewItem($productId);
                $wishlist->save();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error that shows is 'We can\'t specify a wish list.' when I observe event 'customer_login'

Answer (score 0):

So, of course we can think dipper and find really native solution to your task, but lets me provide you fast work around solution.

You can just put the flag at the `customer_register_success` event which will say "Hello, i'm new customer at this store". You can use for example your helper to set this flag, like

`$this->_helper->isNewCustomer = true;`.

It's seems like good workaround, but if you need really nice solution could you please upload your extension code to the GitHub and I will try to find any better way to solve this task.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I had in mind. It does look like a quick one.
I will try it and let you know. If no luck I will give you access to git. Thank you.